# C# Forms unknown StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm getting the oddest Stackoverflow Exception for the last line of the code:

inputPrice is a numericUpDown

```
private void inputPreis_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBoxUnlock.Checked == false)
        {
            if (oldInputPreisValue == 0)
            {
                inputPreis.Value = 5;
            }

            else if (oldInputPreisValue == 5)
            {
                if (inputPreis.Value > oldInputPreisValue)
                    inputPreis.Value = 8;
                else if (inputPreis.Value < oldInputPreisValue)
                    inputPreis.Value = 5;
            }

            else if (oldInputPreisValue == 8)
            {
                if (inputPreis.Value > oldInputPreisValue)
                    inputPreis.Value = 10;
                else if (inputPreis.Value < oldInputPreisValue)
                    inputPreis.Value = 5;
            }
            //etc...

        }

        oldInputPreisValue = Convert.ToInt32(inputPreis.Value);
    }
```

The script is supposed to let the user alter the value of numericUpDown (inputPrice) at fixed values. By checking the checkBoxUnlock checkBox the user can set the value freely.

What's going on here?

Comment: It is already an integer :  oldInputPreisValue = inputPreis.Value;

Comment: When you set the value of `inputPreis`, does that perhaps trigger an event handler?  When you debug this, how many times do you see this method get invoked?

Comment: The method gets invoked over and over but the value of inputPreis does not get set over and over. Only once.

Comment: Each time you set inputPreis.Value in your method, you are triggering the event again.  This is causing a stack overflow.

Comment: I get that. That's why I'm here posting the question. I'm aware that I'm using the event incorrectly but it should not give me an SO error.

Comment: Check the code, oldInputPreisValue starts at 0. So if I type any number inside the numericUpDown while the checkbox is checked it will go into if(oldInputPreisvalue == 0), set InputPreis.value to 5 which will retrigger the event. The second time however oldInputPreisValue has been set to 5, so we go into else if (oldInputPreisValue == 5). Since inputPreis.Value is equal to 5 the event will do nothing. So what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming that when you do something like:

```
inputPreis.Value = 5;
```

Then this will then call the inputPreis_ValueChanged event, which will then set the value again and then call the event again and again and again until you reach the Stack Overflow exception.

I'd recommend storing the value in a local property and setting that instead of resetting the value in the control.

Comment: That is exactly why I am checking for "oldInputPreisValue". If the Price is 5 than it will not try to set the Price to 5 because it's only checking for numbers greater or smaller than 5.

Comment: Have you tried tracing through to see exactly where it goes?  The error suggests to me that it's exactly what I have suggested above.

Comment: @Azul you are incorrectly using the `ValueChanged` event. You should be using `Validating` event and cancel the change if value == xy. Mapping values like you are trying to do will inevitably lead to a mess.